# jest testing apollo provider getting error : TypeError: this.client.watchQuery is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, react-apollo

I was getting error :     Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of Query or as passed props. Wrap the root component in an

then I wrapped component in apollo provider with prop client while testing.

---

```
TypeError: this.client.watchQuery is not a function

  732 |
  733 |   it('should close the overlay when the close button is clicked', () => {
> 734 |     const mandateBatchWrapper = mount(
  735 |       <ApolloProvider client={clientForApollo}>
  736 |         <MandateBatch
  737 |           data={data}
```

---

Comment: did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 3):

Your ApolloClient might be mocked. If you have a file `__mocks__/apollo-client.js` somewhere, ApolloClient will be mocked even without calling `jest.mock('apollo-client')`. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules.